# Is it possible for mysql function to accept null data types on input?

Tags: mysql, function, null, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

like in this false example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(arg1 INT NULL, arg2 INT NULL)
...
```

So for example would be possible to have logic react to situation where in db there is column with integers that could be zero, positive, negative or null (so I can't have a value to collate null into, zero is meanigful) which means that data is not available and the function should return null on output when some arguments are unknown but do a slightly modified version of algorithm when only part of data is available in the row.

or maybe there is function overloading like in C++ ? so I could write multiple functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(arg1 NULL, arg2 INT)
...
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(arg1 INT, arg2 NULL)
...
```

Comment: You don't have to declare function arguments as accepting `NULL`, I think they always can. You just have to check `IF(arg1 IS NULL)` in the function code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare that a function argument can be `NULL`. Declare the function arguments normally. In the SQL, you'll need to check for the `NULL` case specially, because you can't compare null values with `=` (`NULL = NULL` is false).

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ((arg1 IS NULL AND col1 IS NULL) OR (arg1 = col1))
```